# Draw a path around a globe?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, geometry, great-circle

So basically I would like to:

- Draw a path between two positions in Earth, with longitude and latitude coordinates
- Be able to render this path with multiple straight lines (e.g. with OpenGL)
- Specify an altitude, and bonus points for being able to arc over the sphere (e.g. a flight path)
- Doesn't really matter which language it's in. I can translate :)

There is the "great-circle" distance formula, but I'm not sure how I would apply it into this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenGL. Do you want a sequence of points? In spherical coordinates or Cartesian?

Comment: @Beta Yes, a sequence of points in either spherical or cartesian coordinates, whichever is less complex.

Comment: Do you know how to convert between the two? Are you familiar with the idea of a rotation matrix in Cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, here's my approach. If any of the steps are unclear, tell me and I'll elaborate.

1. We're going from **A** to **B**.

   We normalize these vectors, **a** = **A**/|A|, **b** = **B**/|B|.

   (The magnitudes |A| and |B| will be the radius of the Earth if we're staying on the ground.)

   We take the cross-product, **c** = **a** x **b**.

   We will rotate around this vector, **c**, to carry **A** to **B**, and the magnitude of **c** is the cosine of the angle between **A** and **B**: theta = acos(|c|). Pretty cool, huh?

   We don't want to make the trip in one jump, we want n small steps, so we divide theta up. We start at **A**, then at each step we rotate around **c** by an angle theta/n.

   That gives a path along the ground. To get an arc (maybe starting/ending at some altitude), we decide how much altitude to add at each step (very easy in spherical coordinates-- in Cartesian we must scale the vector).

Comment: Can you provide code examples for each step? I'm having difficulty understanding some of these mathematical concepts. You make it sound easy :) So these are Cartesian coordinates, e.g. "A" would be a x, y, z point relative to the center of the Earth? Step three looks like there are several steps, coding wise, that I don't understand how to implement.

Comment: most languages have all the operations listed here as methods of the vector object, otherwise the math is a bit messy, what language are you using?

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba, you won't be able to make this work without understanding the concepts, and to explain them all down to a basic level would take at least half a dozen pages. It might be easier to find an online tutorial on vector algebra, or sit down with a mathy friend. To start: **A** is a vector, from the center of the Earth to a point on (or near) the surface. Whether we choose to write **A** in Cartesian, spherical or any other coordinates, it's the same vector, just as the distance from Paris to Rome is the same whether it's measured in miles or kilometers.

Comment: @Beta Yes I see what you mean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Beta Got it going! Much easier for me to understand when it's translated to code. :) Here's a screenshot: https://plus.google.com/photos/106001808066334889083/albums/5794942733870295681

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba SHALL WE PLAY A GAME?

Comment: @Beta haha it does look like it :)